# Difference between `$...$` and `\m`

Tags: math-mode, context

In [ConTeXt wiki: Math](https://wiki.contextgarden.net/Math), it is said that `\m`, `\math`, `\mathematics` are the same as `$...$`.
My guess is that `\m` wraps `$...$` in ConTeXt the same way as `\(\)` wraps `$...$`, is that so? Are there any advantage or disadvantage between `$...$` and `\m`? (Like, better robustness, or clearer error messages) I really expect that a lookup of manual suffices, but I can't find anything in [ConTeXt, the Manual](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/cont-enp.pdf), nor in [ConTeXt, an Excursion](http://www.pragma-ade.nl/general/manuals/mp-cb-en.pdf).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

First it should be noted that `\m` and `\math` are actually just shorthands for `\mathematics`.

---

The biggest difference between `\m{...}` and `$...$` is that you can nest `\m{...}`.

```
\starttext
\m{e^x = \sum_{k = 0}^\infty \m{\frac{x^k}{k!}}}
\stoptext
```

That allows you to set a value to `\m{...}` and use the value both in text and math mode.

---

In principle `\mathematics` has an optional argument using which you can locally use `\setupmathematics`.  However, when preparing a MWE for this answer I might have found a bug in there (https://mailman.ntg.nl/pipermail/ntg-context/2019/094137.html).  Adding `\everymathematics` manually fixes the problem.

```
\starttext

The greek letter should be upright here

\m[lcgreek=normal]{\varphi}

\m[lcgreek=normal]{\the\everymathematics\varphi}

\stoptext
```

---

An additional convenience is that `\m{...}` is a command, whereas `$...$` is not, so you can use `\m` in places where a command is required, e.g. in setups.

---

Personally I still use `$...$` all the time because of editor shortcuts and syntax highlighting.